# PHP Exception within a try catch block not being caught unless the print function is called?

Tags: php

**TL;DR:**

My PHP-Exception only get caught, if i use a print-statement in the catch-block.

---

I am seeing some strange behaviour with a PHP try catch block. My PHP version is 7.0.14.

Here is a method that I've defined which simply explodes a string and stores the result in memory. If the exploded string doesn't have the expected amount of constituent parts, an Exception will be thrown.

```
public function importString($string) {

    // separate the string with the delimiter.
    $separated = explode($this->delimiter, $string);

    // If there is a different number of segments to specified id's throw exception.
    if (count($separated) != count($this->ids)) {
        $class = static::class;
        throw new \Exception("Invalid Pseudo ID '{$string}' for type '{$class}'.");
    }

    //store separated id strings
    foreach($separated as $i => $item) {
        $this->data[$this->ids[$i]] = $item;
    }
}
```

This method is contained within a class called PseudoId from which the two classes below inherit.

Below is the code that calls the method defined above; the majority of the time I expect the imported string to be constructed from three different values (e.g. "one_two_three") but on occasion there can be strings with four components (e.g. "one_two_three_four"), therefore I first attempt to import the string into the object that expects the string to have three components, falling back to the object that expects four.

```
try {
    //Added later for debug
    throw new \Exception("error");

    $productInfo = new PseudoIdFeedProduct(0, 0, 0);
    $productInfo->importString($data['productId']);

} catch (\Exception $e) {

    //Added later for debug
    print "caught.";

    $productInfo = new PseudoIdFeedProductIndividualBilling(0, 0, 0, 0);
    $productInfo->importString($data['productId']);
}

// Added for debug
var_dump($productInfo);
```

Now here's the weird part: When passing in a string with four components, the Exception thrown in PseudoIdFeedProduct::importString() isn't caught. So for the sake of debugging I added an Exception to the top of the try block, calling the print function in the catch block as a check and it worked. So I removed the exception at the top of the try block, and it still worked. Slightly baffled, I removed the call to the print function and it stopped working...

Whether the thrown Exception is caught depends on whether the print function is called in the catch block, I added and removed it a couple of times to double check.

Clearly I don't want to have to call the print function here, what am I doing wrong here and how can I get this to work as expected?

Comment: simplfy the question! :/

Comment: Could you provide a test file? I tried to [reproduce it](https://pastebin.com/umFkDGZv) with what you've given but it works for me with and without the print statement, not sure what I made different. Make sure you have errors enabled too, my guess it's that it's a logic error elsewhere.

Comment: I tried to reproduce it in isolation and I got the expected behaviour, there must be an error elsewhere in my logic like you say. Thanks :)